# Changing btn resource in the middle of a function

Tags: android, button, thread-sleep

I'm trying to create a small pause between the player move and the computer move(comp call game when the case that's chosen is case:1). The problem is that in my debug I see that my buttons resources change together, and only in the end of game function, after the player and the computer played. I expected that after "drawTheMove" the btn will change.

```
public void game(Point p, Button btn) {
    switch (turn % numOfplayers) {
        case 0: {
            if (!checkIfGotWinner()) {
                if (isValid(p)) {
                    addChoice(p);
                    drawTheMove(btn);
                    turn++;
                    if(!isHuman2) {
                        getUserClicks = false;
                        comp.playYourGameBitch(this);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            if (!checkIfGotWinner() && isValid(p)) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(400);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                addChoice(p);
                drawTheMove(btn);
                getUserClicks = true;
                turn++;
            }
            checkIfGotWinner();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

drawTheMove:

```
public void drawTheMove(Button btn) {
    btn.setText(Integer.toString(getNumOfClick()));
    Player player = getLastPlayerPlay();
    btn.setBackgroundResource(player.getImageId());
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Draws in Android don't occur until control has been returned to the Looper in the main thread.  They do not occur instantly.  All setText will do is invalidate the view, which will tell us on the next draw command from the looper that it needs to redraw itself.

Also, never sleep on the main thread.  Because of the above, a sleep on the main thread makes your app unresponsive.

Comment: Thank for your detailed explanation !
I just not sure how should I handle this problem. Should I split my function to two functions, one for the player and one for the computer?